# Trigger PRs in Jenkins multibranch pipelline for a particular target branch

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Hi I think my question is quite clear from the topic if not let me clarify it more with a example.

Suppose I have a branch master in my repository so now i want to trigger pipeline only when a pull request is generated against master branch. I'm using Github.

Comment: Are you using Github? or what system?

Comment: yeas I am using github

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code, it uses `scripted pipeline` syntax:

```
properties([pipelineTriggers([githubPush()])])

node {
    git url: 'https://github.com/someone/something.git', branch: 'master'
}
```

Take a look at [this issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35132) for more info.